# Find text with wildcard

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I am looking in a `/etc/hosts` file for hosts that should contain servers that look at least like this:

```
mobile.example.com
more.mobile.example.com
```

and NOT example.com

I want to search with a wildcard like this:

`sed`/`awk`/`find`/`grep`/ `word.word.word < path/to/inputfile > path/to/outputfile` where word consists of `[A-Z, a-z, 0-9]`

Please write 'sed','awk','find' or 'grep' code for this.

Comment: Is this a homework question?  By "a hosts file" do you mean **the** `/etc/hosts` file?  Why do you want to search a specific, invalid, way?  Did someone give you that guidance?

Comment: Your examples are also confusing.  Initially I thought you want to find anything that ends with `mobile.example.com` but given your example search it seems like you want to find anything that is at least 2 subdomains away from a tld?

Comment: @Jesse_b thank you for answering. yes, its a "/etc/hosts" file and yes, i only want hosts listed in my outputfile that have at least 3 words like: mobile.example.com and NOT example.com

Comment: Are you including `127.0.0.1` as having at least three words?

Comment: @doneal24 sorry, no.

Comment: edit question to show what you have tried. As you know which file then you don't need `find`. As you are only searching not modifying then you don't need `sed`, and `awk` is more power than you need. So use `grep`. Read manual, try it, then ask for help, posting what you tried.

Comment: I made an edit. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: What about `www.example.com`?

Comment: @Jesse_b without www.example.com. I'm looking for a search code with a placeholder like an "asterisk".

Comment: @superbyte: I'm not quite sure what you just said.  Should `www.example.com` be included in your search or not?

Comment: If a `word` consists of `[A-Za-z0-9]`, then you'll have to work to eliminate `127.0.0.1` (four words). Also, host names can also have other characters in them such as `-`.

Comment: @doneal24: Yeah, technically 127.0.0.1.com could be a valid domain as well, this seems like a tall order.

Comment: its a clean hosts file without 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1

Comment: @superbyte: the issues we are discussing apply to **all** ip addresses, if your hosts file doesn't contain ip addresses what is it doing in the first place?  Also "Clean" seems subjective, however objectively a "clean hosts file" will contain 127.0.0.1...it is the default entry.

Comment: @Jesse_b ok, here goes. im helping "stevenblack" github hostsfile to grow. so i installed a firefox extension for blocking hosts in the google search and loaded it with hosts i got. then i did a google search and added more hosts to the file by clicking on the "block" link. google gives me of course new sites like: mobile.example.com. now i have a file containing "1000" new hosts. i want to search in this file for hosts so that i can manually add "newhost.com". can you give me grep code to find all lines that look like this: mobile.example.com and mobile.example2.com and so on.

Comment: @superbyte: Please read through the comments above, address all the questions and try to understand all the caveats of what you are asking.  You haven't really stated any new and valuable information.  Your problem is just not as simple as you think it is and almost any attempt we make to solve it will likely either return things you don't want it to, or hide things you don't want it to.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/hosts` entries can have one or more hostnames per IP address, so we need to check each hostname (i.e. all fields except the first field) to see if it has 2 or more `.` characters in it.

For example:

```
awk '{for (f=2;f<=NF;f++) {if (split($f,array,/\./)>2) {print;last}}}' /etc/hosts
```

or, with linefeeds and indentation added to improve readability:

```
awk '
  {
    for (f=2;f<=NF;f++) {
      if (split($f,array,/\./) > 2) {
        print;
        last;
      }
    }
  }' /etc/hosts
```

This will print every line in `/etc/hosts` where any of the hostnames have at least 2 literal `.` characters.

It iterates over each field in an input line and uses awk's `split()` function to do this, splitting on `.` characters.  A string split into elements by a delimiter will always have 1 more element than the number of delimiters, so the test has to be `> 2` rather than `>= 2`.  e.g. "example" would have one element, itself.  "example.com" would have two elements ("example" and "com").  "mobile.example.com" would have 3.

`split()` also splits the string into an array, but for this task we're only interested in the return value (the number of elements) and ignore the array.

Once the script has found **one** hostname with two or more `.` characters, it prints the entire line, breaks out of the for loop (with `last`), and moves on to the next input line.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Actually, reading your comments, it’s not a real hosts file, but just a list of domin names, so you seem to be satisfied filtering all lines with at least two dots:

```
grep '\..*\.' hostfile
```

If it is important that the domain is at the beginning of the line, use

```
grep '^[[:alnum:]]*\..*\.' hostfile
```

Comment: thank you also very much. it gave me the output file i was looking for :-) can you add "-www.example.com" to this grep search ?

Comment: The first pattern will also find the address with leading dash, for the second add the dash to the collection: `[-[:alnum:]]`